# How do I avoid getting no-new without commenting out?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have the following to create an express server...

```
export class SearchApp extends BaseApp{
    constructor(){
        super(port);
        SearchRoute(this.express);
    }
}
```

The key here is I extend another class that contains some common setup. The problem is when I use this in a server.mjs file (`new SearchApp()`) lint throws and error...

> 3:1  error  Do not use 'new' for side effects  no-new

How *should* I do this? IIFE does seem to work but seems hacky...

```
(()=>new SearchApp())();
```

Comment: `/*eslint no-new:off */` as a comment on the same line as the offending code should work.  Or is that what you mean by "without commenting out"?

Comment: What is `SearchRoute`?

Comment: Well, don't use `class` constructors for side effects, that's what the warning is saying. Why do you want to use a `class` at all, what do you do with its instances? What is `BaseApp`?

Comment: @Bergi It seemed to be the best pattern given the way I needed to share functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `class` syntax for everything, especially if you don't need to keep state and store the instance anywhere. Class inheritance is the wrong tool to share common setup code. Make it a simple factory function:

```
export function initSearchApp() {
    const app = new BaseApp(port); // not sure whether this should be a constructor either
    SearchRoute(app.express);
}
```

```
initSearchApp(); // no es-lint complaints :-)
```